# A conical white flower

Tags: flowers

[image].   Is this a picture of any flower. Please let me know [image]

Comment: Protea cynaroides 'King White' - it doesn't have any pink anywhere at any stage of the flower's development.

Answer (score 5):

They're flower buds of a white cultivar of [King Protea](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protea_cynaroides) (*Protea cynaroides*) before it's started opening even a little. King protea is the national flower of South Africa and has the largest flower head of all protea.

[image]

Once it starts opening, it becomes more obvious it's a protea.
[image]

Comment: How are you posting the pictures?  I used to be able to do this, much more attractive and simplified but maybe it was this Australian Seed site that had its repens picture in a shortened format?

Comment: Doesn't seem if I use the app, my tablet or my phone, only maybe one site out of 10 will load an image (.jpg) on SE - even if it's something like Wikipedia Common and permission to use. So I basically save images, post from my gallery and after they've loaded, delete them. All I know is something's buggy. I deleted the SE app as answers that have already been posted won't show up on the app till later which causes problems for me answering.

Comment: Does anything ever work correctly all the time? Nope. Especially when a myriad of designers with conflicting interests come with the territory. I don't bother complaining but simply look for ways to deal with it so I can still use it.

Comment: Thanks, Jude.  I am one of THOSE people who get a new toy and for some weird reason I hold onto the instructions but don't read them very closely until I absolutely have to.  I try on this site to find the rules and regulations but I always end up in never never land.  Just one of my own little problems born from having too little patience!

Comment: The ID is correct, but the images provided are incorrect - there is a Protea cynaroides called King White which remains white , even when its open, it does not have any pink tinge to the petals, fully open one shown here http://www.proteaflora.com.au/our-plants/safari-sunset-4

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Bamboo. Since you're in the UK, you have access to **many** public gardens, Kew being one of the foremost. Decent gardens where I am are very few and most entail long drives, often through crowded slow traffic to reach. Have you ever seen this in the flesh? I'd die to spend a spring/summer season in the UK visiting gardens!

Answer (score 1):

This has got to be Protea repens...[Protea repens](http://australianseed.com/shop/item/protea-repens-white-form/new-this-month)

Welp, the flower looks right, got to be Protea but the leaves are wrong!  Jude's answer has better leaf Id but it isn't this waxy white of repens. I'll go with Jude's answer because of the leaves.  Has to be Protea, dog gone you Jude!  Grins!